# Python make transaction system by reading json files

Tags: python

I am working on a problem

```
def update_transactions(file_path: str, transaction_list: list):
"""
You are part of a team tasked to create an application that helps bankers by saving their transactions for them.
Your job within the project is to implement the feature that actually saves the transactions to the hard drive.
The scope of your task is that you will be given a file path to where the data should be written and a list of
bank transaction objects to be written to the file. The file will contain a JSON array of transactions that the
banker previously saved. The bankers at this bank are silly sometimes and they make duplicate transactions, your
function should remove the duplicate transactions in the transaction_list and update the existing transaction list
saved in the file with the new transactions. Make sure when you are preforming the update of the new transactions
that you overwrite old transactions (transactions that already exist in the file) with duplicate new transactions
(transactions that are found in the transaction_list). You will know that a transaction is a duplicate if it has
 the same ID.

In the end the file should contain a JSON list with transaction Objects that have been updated with the new
information from the transaction_list. The JSON list should contain no transactions with the same ID.

The transaction object referred to here in is outlined below. In actual testing of your code the professors
transaction object will be used, which will have all the documented functionality.

class Transaction:

    def __init__(self, id:int, type:str, amount:float):
        self.id:int = id
        self.type:str = type
        self.amount:float = amount

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Transaction[%s] %s $%s' (self.id, self.type, self.amount)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.id)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return hasattr(other,'id') and other.id == self.id

:param file_path: A path to file blank file that holds a JSON list of existing transaction and where the new
 transaction data should be written
:param transaction_list: A list of transaction
:return: None
"""
```

Although, I think I have an understanding of reading json files in Python, I have been struggling with this problem for days. Should I be opening the JSON files in the very first part of the method or making additional methods to solve it?

Comment: Is `update_transactions()` a given function to implement or something of your own creation?  If given ,the type for `transaction_list` is a list, which means that it should already be in the format of a list of key-value collections.  JSON is usually represented as a string.  Also, the `__str__(self)` method is missing a percent sign (%) between the string and tuple.

Comment: If you're importing data from a file, however, you could try [json.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json%20load#json.load) from the standard library to import and process data before handling it.

Comment: @MarkMoretto 

I should be implementing the method update_transactions() to perform the task written in the comment